# Curl not returning response

Tags: linux, curl, proxy, certificates

I have a scenario where I was using `curl --noproxy "*" https://..` to get the response but suddenly when I use it now it doesn't return me the response instead it says

```
curl: (60) Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

now when I use `curl -k https://` it gives me response.
I am not sure what went wrong and what could be the cause for this.

Any idea how to not use `curl -k` insecure option ?

Answer (score 0):

You can load a valid certificate for the site you are trying to connect to with the `--cacert /path/to/crt/file`. The `-k` option is usually used for self-signed certs, although I always try and use `--cacert`.

Answer (score 0):

If this happened recently, maybe the remote certificate was signed  by an authority not present in your certificate store. If you have no doubt about remote site being legitimate, -k is an option. However:

- you can try to update your system to refresh ca-certificates package
- you can get information about certificates using openssl s_client which has many options to debug SSL things.

  ex:
  $ openssl s_client -connect google.com:443

  - Also: you cant get additional detail on certificates by extending the command like this:

  $ openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 | openssl x509 -noout -text

which includes validity dates, for example :

```
... Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 5230064140940427690 (0x4894eba0494341aa)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=Google Inc, CN=Google Internet Authority G2
        Validity
            Not Before: Feb 13 10:55:29 2018 GMT
            Not After : May  8 10:40:00 2018 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=California, L=Mountain View, O=Google Inc, CN=*.google.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:d7:14:f9:54:c2:48:c4:4c:be:22:b1:59:23:79:
      ...
```

Comment: is this anything related to user ?
I had created a different user and assigned root permissions

Comment: no, the ca-certificates are usually globally accessible. However, if it wroked with another user, you should try again with that. And if so look for differences in environment.

Comment: okay , thanks for the explanation. two questions now, 1.  if I use curl -k is there any harm is this insecure ?
2. I remember I had created a user then assigned root permissions to it then in root profile i had exported the proxy settings (when ever I do sudo su root it redirects me to my home) now few days back I created a new user and assigned root permissions to it is there any relation that I should del that user ?

Comment: 1. "-k" option : this option prevents remote certificate from being verified. As a consequence, you are never sure the communication is actually going to the server you think it goes.

Comment: 2. I don't think these are linked. What is the result of openssl s_client -connect <yoursite>:443 ?

Comment: here is the o/pofopensll s_client -connect
`getaddrinfo: Servname not supported for ai_socktype
connect:errno=0`

Comment: looks like you did a typo in the command. Do you successfully run s_client to google ? (openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 ). If so make sure you enter the correct address/port for your server (without https:// ! ).

Comment: Yup It shows me connected but at end of my certificate I also see this 
`Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)`

Comment: And this too `No client certificate CA names sent`

Comment: Does that mean my certificate has expired ? from where can I install a new one ?

Comment: I think the server certificate has expired, I did an update in post to show how to see validity dates.